# Facebook Insights for Website

Tags: facebook, web, insight

I am trying to setup Facebook Insights for my website at http://pixls.co
I have created an app and Facebook is asking me to put

in my code... which I have done a few weeks ago...

but when I try to click the "get insight" button, it kept saying
" No admin data found at root webpage http://pixls.co/. Insights requires admin data at this root webpage for the specified URL pixls.co "

am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your page in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpixls.co%2F). It's choking on your page and not reading any of your og:meta tags. If you click on the "See what our scraper sees" link at the bottom of the page, you will see it is ignoring all your HTML declaration tags.

I've had this problem before. The Facebook parser does not like white space at the beginning of your HTML.

When I view your page source, I see a blank line before your `<!DOCTYPE>` tag and another between that and your `<html>` tag. Get rid of those and see if your problem goes away.

Fix that, make sure it parses correctly in the debugger, and give insights ~24 hours to populate and check again.

Comment: oh! Thanks so much! I think it is working. The blank line was somehow introduced to the site via a wordpress theme... while I still have no idea why there is a new blank line at the start (it's not there in the code!), I swapped out the current theme with the default and the line is gone... and Facebook accepted my site just like that. Thanks for the heads up with this useful info though :)

Comment: For WP, try getting rid of all the closing `?>` tags in your theme files. PHP doesn't need them. Any whitespace after a closing tag will be echoed.